# Inline tag edit on pending edit questions

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I just recently hit 10k rep and saw that I can do in-line tag edits on posts, however this doesn't seem to work on posts that have pending edits to be approved - is this by design?

[Handy link to edit queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) if anyone 10k+ wants to try

*^^(I know you can't do this in review queue, just providing link to make it easier to find questions that you can open and try it on...)*

Answer (score 6):

I would guess this is by design. Any pending edits in the queue will be rejected if a 2K user edits the question independent from the review (bypassing the suggestion). Instead, users are encouraged to approve or reject the suggested edit, and/or add additional edits on top of that.

If you want to edit the tags on a post in the review queue, chose "Improve Edit" and change the tags.