# Ability to edit tags (inline tag edit) even during a pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits

I've been thinking about this for a while and it doesn't appear to have already been asked (as a feature request), unless it was a bad idea; please see the latter part of my closing sentence.

I did find this question ["*Inline tag edit on pending edit questions*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323272/1415724) where the answer given states/thinks that it is "by design".

I would like to know if it were possible to be able to edit tags with the "Edit tags" option (inline tag edit) during a pending/suggested edit, where a relevant tag (or tags) should have been added (or removed) during the time it was pending/not approved. This being a 20k+ feature I believe.

Sometimes I (and possibly other 20k+ members) may have already rejected an edit because I/they felt there was no improvement done to it and (I/we) may have left the question or acted too quickly to reject it and only thought of the tags after it was too late and cannot improve the edit on their part.

Or maybe because it was taking too long for the edit to be approved, or other reason(s), and the relevant tag(s) was/were never added, which probably could have made a difference with relevance to the question and for people following those tags that could have provided them with (faster) help.

Do you feel that this would be a good (added) feature, or will it cause havoc/problems for the edit queue?